# Matlab: Finding values higher than 150 and grouping them with their corresponding time

Tags: matlab, max

This might be a simple task, but as im new to matlab, i have not been able to figure it out.

I have a matrix with two relevant columns, first column consists of hour-by-hour measurements of electricity consumption over the span of a month(so around 740 values). The second column consists of datenum values corresponding to each measurement.

The electricity-measurements have clear peaks, and I want to sum up each peak, from a lower boundary of 150, up to the peak and "down" to 150 again. Each month there are roughly 10-15 peaks, and i want to sum up each peak and store it in a vector together with its corresponding time so i can identify where the peaks occur,and how big they are. Im able to find the consumption values, but have trouble getting the corresponding times from the second column.

Does anyone have a solution to how I can do this?

Sorry for the confusing problem description.

Many Thanks

Edit:

Here is a sample from the data:

```
0.1250    2.0130    0.0080    0.0030    0.0150         0         0
0.1299    2.0130    0.0080    0.0030    0.0160         0         0
0.1368    2.0130    0.0080    0.0030    0.0170         0         0
0.1333    2.0130    0.0080    0.0030    0.0180         0         0
0.1343    2.0130    0.0080    0.0030    0.0190         0         0
0.1349    2.0130    0.0080    0.0030    0.0200         0         0
0.1250    2.0130    0.0080    0.0030    0.0210         0         0
0.1150    2.0130    0.0080    0.0030    0.0220         0         0
0.1150    2.0130    0.0080    0.0030    0.0230         0         0
0.1000    2.0130    0.0080    0.0040         0         0         0
0.1000    2.0130    0.0080    0.0040    0.0010         0         0
0.0950    2.0130    0.0080    0.0040    0.0020         0         0
0.0900    2.0130    0.0080    0.0040    0.0030         0         0
0.0850    2.0130    0.0080    0.0040    0.0040         0         0
0.0850    2.0130    0.0080    0.0040    0.0050         0         0
0.0848    2.0130    0.0080    0.0040    0.0060         0         0
0.0893    2.0130    0.0080    0.0040    0.0070         0         0
0.0883    2.0130    0.0080    0.0040    0.0080         0         0
0.0817    2.0130    0.0080    0.0040    0.0090         0         0
0.0836    2.0130    0.0080    0.0040    0.0100         0         0
0.0831    2.0130    0.0080    0.0040    0.0110         0         0
0.1017    2.0130    0.0080    0.0040    0.0120         0         0
0.1021    2.0130    0.0080    0.0040    0.0130         0         0
0.0949    2.0130    0.0080    0.0040    0.0140         0         0
```

All values are 1.0e+03 *

The first values are the consumption values and the rest are the datevec values for each consumption value. I need to be able to pick out the values from the first column that are above 150 and store them with their corresponding datevec values.

Hopes this helps. Im completely new to this so sorry for my 'noobish' questioning!

EDIT:
Im very new to matlab so haven't gotten it to work.

Gonna try a more "easy" approach.

The data i have is 740x1

sample of the data:

94.9997

89.9986

104.9981

139.8430

158.6546

161.6176

169.8047

178.4623

192.4402

207.0930

199.7369

190.2221

181.6872

173.1552

159.8161

149.9443

134.9956

129.9899

114.9989

99.9990

89.9990

89.9991

84.9991

79.9991

79.9989

84.9901

94.9928

149.9995

174.9977

174.7706

179.7816

179.8007

203.4999

208.6901

209.1134

199.3191

183.5979

164.4079

154.8898

140.0000

129.9494

124.9923

124.9987

104.9993

109.9994

94.9995

94.9995

84.9995

84.9995

84.9953

85.0000

84.8889

83.7396

I need a program that goes through the data and picks out the numbers higher than 150 and groups them. I realised that i don't really need the time, i only need to separate the peaks from each other.

I need it to run something like this:

%for loop that runs through the data

%picks out the first set of values over 150

%stores them in a matrix: column 1

%picks out the next set of values over 150

%stores them in the same matrix: column 2

%picks out the next set of values over 150

%stores them in the matrix: column 3

Appreciate all of your help, and I'm sure i could use the previous suggestions if i had a better understanding of matlab and programming in general.
Sorry for all the trouble!

Comment: Please post sample values and preferrably an [mcve](http://stackoverflow/help/mcve).

Comment: if you have the indices of the consumption peaks, say `k`, you  can index into those of the second column with `col(k,2)`

Comment: From your Datapoints, none are higher than 150, even with 10^3. For readability, please improve the structuring of your question. To clarify: you want the peak from the first value higher than 150 to the last value higher than 150?

Comment: I have consumption values for 1 year, divided into the months of the year, so i have roughly 12 x 740 values. I didn't notice when i copied in some sample data that that particular part didn't have any values higher than 150 so i apologise for the confusion. Yes, i want to be able to set a lower boundary, at say 150, and sum up the peak from the first value above 150 to the last value above 150. Many thanks for all your answers, your all a  huge help!  Im gonna try them out and let you know what works!

Comment: The codes provided below are feasible solutions to your problem. I suggest that you work through a Matlab tutorial and try to understand the code. If you have specific questions, about some programming features, add a comment with your question below the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

This is not very matlabish... but it could help you get started:

```
sum = 0; %keeps track of the sum in the interval
max = 0; %keeps track of the peak
maxi = 0; %keeps track of the peak index
aux1 = 1; %aux variable
minv = 100;

for i = 1:length(A)

    if i==1 && A(i,1)<minv

    elseif A(i,1) >= minv
        sum = sum + A(i,1);
        if A(i,1) > max
            max = A(i,1);
            maxi = i;
        end

    elseif A(i,1) < minv && A(i-1,1) >= minv
        B(aux1,1) = sum;
        B(aux1,2:7) = A(maxi,2:7);
        sum = 0;
        max = 0;
        maxi = 0;
        aux1 = aux1 + 1;

    elseif A(i,1) < minv && A(i-1,1) < minv

    end
end
```

Running that code with your sample data gives:

```
1349.2        2013           8           3          17           0           0
 203.8        2013           8           4          13           0           0
```

The first column gives the sum from the first 100 to the last 100 (I used 100 because none of the values of your data was bigger than 150, you can change this value by changing `minv`) and the rest of the columns corresponds to the date and hour of when the peak in that particular interval of time occured, if necessary you can add a new column to add the actual peak value too.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the right rows with high consumption with logical indexing. Let's say the name of your matrix is `data`.

But before, I would improve the structure of the data, e.g. with structs:

```
% structure data and identify high consumption measurements
measurements.consumption     = data(:,1);
measurements.datevec         = data(:,2:end);
measurements.ixHigh          = measurements.consumption>150;

% get measurements with high consumption
peakMeasurements.comsumption = measurements.consumption(measurements.ixHigh);
peakMeasurements.datevecs    = measurements.datevecs(measurements.ixHigh,:);
```

If you're lucky and you own Matlab 2013b or newer, you can use [tables](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/09/10/introduction-to-the-new-matlab-data-types-in-r2013b/) to store your data more human readable.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Matlab capabilities for logical indexing (as mentioned by JaBe) this solution should be faster than looping over all elements of A(:,:)

```
% Generate Demo data
A=[]
A(1:100,1)=20+ (1:100); % Time values
A(1:100,2)=rand(100,1) % scatter
A(20:25,2) = 155 % first peak
A(44:79,2) = 157 % second peak

% Add column with index
Aix=[(1:size(A,1))', A]; % [Index, time, Value]

% Just the peak values
B=Aix(Aix(:,3)>150,:)

% Collection of Peak Values
Peaks = B(1,:)
i_start=B(1,1)
for i=2:size(B,1)
   if B(i,1)==B(i-1,1)+1 % Datapoint belongs to previous peak
       Peaks(end,3) = Peaks(end,3) + B(i,3);   % Sum Value to Peak Result
   else % Generate Dataset for new Peak
       Peaks = [Peaks ; B(i,:)];   % Add new Dataset
   end

end;

disp (' Start Index | Start time | Sum Value')
disp ( Peaks)
```

Will give your the following result

```
Start Index | Start time | Sum Value
          20          40         930
          44          64        5652
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the name of your vector be data. This will give you the sums of all the peaks:

```
sumvec = [];
while(1)
    beginindex = find(data>150,1);
    if length(beginindex)==0
        break;
    end
    data = data(beginindex:end);
    endindex = find(data<150,1);
    if length(beginindex)==0
        break;
    end

    sumvec = [sumvec sum(data(beginindex:endindex))];
    data = data(endindex:end);

end
```

I think some boundary conditions will break, but otherwise, is this what you want?